# My AutoML Image classification model has been training for longer than the requested node hours

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am new to VertexAI. I am trying out its AutoML feature for a single label image classification problem. I followed all recommended steps to upload my images (Jpegs with resolution 720 x 1024) and had a manual split of data (Total images 1001 for label 1 and 870 for label 2, split approximately to 80,10 and 10% for training, validation and test). I set the requested node hours to 8 and started training. The training has been going on for more than 11 and half hours at which time I cancelled the training. Prior to this I had requested 20 node hours and the training kept going on for more than 1 day and 11 hours for the same dataset.
So my questions are:

1. Why does the training continue for more time than requested through the node hour budget?
2. Is there a way to check how the model training is progressing? Any logs for training, intermediate values of model performance through the epochs, etc. that can be accessed?
   Basically, I have no idea if and how the training is progressing.

I have read through the documentation on vertex AI that I could find and other blogs and posts on the internet, but could not find any specific answers. Some posts says their image classification model with Vertex AI AutoML trained within a few hours, with about 1000s of images.

I would much appreciate any help with this. Thanks

Comment: Were you able to find an answer to this? I have same questions and the official docs are very lacking

Comment: Did you let it run to the end? And I assume cancelling the training will lead to costs, but no model?

Comment: The training time will always take longer as there are tasks such as setup, teardown and validation of datasets that are not involved in node hours. But difference between 1 day 11 hours and 20 hours is quite a lot.

Comment: same for me, for only 60 training jpg file, i set 8 node hours as budget, but now it is more than 4 days and it is still training... no official doc regarding this... i have to cancel the job manuelly